# Importing of Excel Sheet With New Rows Added

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, sql-server-2008-r2

I am doing importing of excel sheet into the database through the C# program, I have no problem with importing for first time, however subsequently, when I want to import the same excel sheet, but with new rows, I am not able to and I receive the following error:

```
Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_Students'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Students'.
The statement has been terminated.
```

My SQL statement is as follow:

```
INSERT INTO Students (Student_Id, Student_name, Subject_Class, Subject_Id, Student_Course)
SELECT Student_Id, Student_name,Subject_Class, Subject_Id, Student_Course 
FROM Students WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Students.*)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your insert statement doesn't make sense as you're inserting into the Student table from the Student table. The error is from attempting to insert duplicate rows by (primary key Student_Id) into the Student table.

What excel library are you using? Give linq to excel a go if you haven't already: https://code.google.com/p/linqtoexcel/

If you'd rather not spend time learning linq to excel, you could always just delete all records in the Student table that exist in your spreadsheet (by Student_Id), then insert them all from the spreadsheet again.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. I used the following statement:

```
Merge into bkTeachers as tab1 using(select * from Teachers) as tab2 on tab1.Teacher_Id=tab2.Teacher_Id when matched then update set tab1.Teacher_Name=tab2.Teacher_Name,tab1.Password=tab2.Password when not matched then insert values(tab2.Teacher_Id,tab2.Teacher_Name,tab2.Password);
```